# WSO2 - Clustering AS on Custom Polling Applications

Tags: wso2, load-balancing, wso2-as

We have developed a custom JAX-WS application that essentially achieves two things.

1. Exposes a few web service methods to perform some functionality.
2. Utilizes org.quartz.Scheduler to schedule and execute some polling tasks that monitors and processes data on a few database tables. (The logic here is slightly complex, hence a custom application was chosen over the use of WSO2 DSS)

This application is uploaded on WSO2 AS 5.2.1 and runs quite seamlessly. However, I'm unsure what will happen if we have to cluster the AS application server. Logically, I would think that each node will have its own instance of the custom application running within it, and hence its own scheduler. Would this not increase the risk of processing the same record, across both instances. Is my interpretation of the above scenario correct, from a clustering perspective?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.You are correct.In cluster of app server nodes each nodes will have its own instance of the application.In your case each node will have seperate scheduler.You may consider using [tasks](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/Working+with+Tasks) from ESB 4.9.0. there WSO2 has added coordination support to work in cluster environment.